# displaying Crystal Report Control in report viewer

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports

I am very new to Crystal Report . Now, I used Crystal Report in my C# window application.
    Firstly , I added a textbox control and set all border to none .
Then I used report viewer to show this report .
    When I run this , it show like that.
    [image]

Then I click on this textbox control , report show like that
[image]

It show how long my control is .
 I don't want to show user how high my control and how long my control.
 I want to show my report like first picture whenever it is .
How could I do to show like first picture .
 Which properties should I use to display correctly.

With Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have You bind datasource to report document?

Comment: I have not bind any datasource in above example. But I have bind datasource to my real report document and it is the same with above example

Comment: You need to give datasource dynamically when you are showing data into report. Only giving datasource while creating report will not work. if you want code for setting datasource in report, just let me know.